# Replace a reply in case of an error

Tags: javascript, hapi.js

Is it possible to regret a reply (reply() invoked in a route handler) inside the handler if an error is happening later in the request flow?

I want to catch the error and return status code 500 with an appropriate message instead of the initial reply.

```
function(request, reply) {
  reply(200)
  try {
    // code causing an error
  } catch(error) {
    // reset previous reply
    reply(Boom.badImplementation(error))
  }
}
```

Comment: Reply returns an error as well as a success, it is basically a wrapper around callback?!?

Comment: I have added some code to explain the flow

Comment: Once you call reply, control is handed back to hapi, why would you have a try catch after a reply??

Comment: I'm building a library based on hapijs where HTTP resources are like Ruby on Rails controllers, but much more simple. I'm implementing the before and after filters like before*-event and after*-event.

Answer (score -2):

Please be a bit more specific. Do you want to know how to catch an error or want to know how to return an error status. Later please check hapi-status node module. npm install hapi-status.

1. npm install hapi-status
2. var hstatus = require("hapi-status")
3. Now in your catch block please add the following ->
   return hstatus.XXXX(reply, {"error": error});

If you refer to the documentation of hapi-status and choose an appropriate value for XXXX. In your case it should be return hstatus.internalServerError(.......)

Comment: @Jacob, The moment you add reply("Your Contents") the further execution halts and the response is returned. In you catch block you need to handle the exception and then as suggested by me previously use  hapi-status node module.